# How to convert a list of words to adjacency lists in an efficient way

Tags: python, graph, adjacency-list

Say I have a list of words. If a word's last letter is the same with another word's first letter, then we can connect them together. We don't connect the word with itself.The input elements are distinct.

Example: apple - elephant - tower - rank

I implemented it as this.

```
def transform(lst):
    graph = []
    for picked in lst:
        link = []
        i = lst.index(picked)
        rest = lst[:i]+lst[i+1:]
        for compare in rest:
            if picked[-1] == compare[0]:
                link.append(compare)
        if len(link) != 0:
            graph.append(link)
    return graph
```

I don't know if I can still improve it.

=======================================================================

I think I should change

`if len(link) != 0:
   graph.append(link)`

to

`graph.append(link)`

Otherwise, the order of the adjacent lists will be mixed

Comment: I just run your code giving as input ['apple','elephant','tower','rank'] and I got this output: [['elephant'], ['tower'], ['rank']] looks that you are not concatenating them and loosing 'apple' is it correct or do I miss understood?

Comment: Of course you can do that. However, I suppose the input should be larger. In the case the input is `['apple', 'elephant', 'tower', 'rank']`, we get the output `[['elephant'], ['tower'], ['rank']]` is still good. apple is connected with elephant, elephant is connected with tower, tower is connected with rank, rank doesn't connect with anything.

Comment: yeah but you lost the 'apple' because it's not in your output. plus if u give as input ['apple','carlo','apple','elephant','tower','rank'] you get [['elephant'], ['elephant'], ['tower'], ['rank']] and it doesn't look than correct... could u pls give me a bigger example?

Comment: It's a graph theory problem. You might want to implement a class node, edge and graph. I would recommend you this site for informations: https://www.python-course.eu/graphs_python.php

Comment: @Carlo 1585 Sorry I don't have any example. The example above I just made it up. I lost the 'apple', but I don't care about 'apple'. I only care about what 'apple' connect with.

Comment: @Mathieu Yea I know it's graph theory problem. In my case, I need to determine which words should connect first.

Comment: @user8314628 What do you mean by connect first? Once you got all the edges it's simply about finding the cycles and the left outs.

Comment: Do you want to print EVERY possible chain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should start by identifying the two things you're grouping by here. Ending letters and starting letters. Drop all the words into two dicts, keyed by each, and you'll end up with *much* faster lookups. `list.index` is a *killer* for efficiency, with each lookup costing *O(n)*

```
from collections import defaultdict

startswith, endswith = defaultdict(list), defaultdict(list)

wordlist = ['apple','elephant','tower','rank']
for word in wordlist:
    startswith[word[0]].append(word)
    endswith[word[-1]].append(word)
```

Then it should be a fairly simple graph traversal problem.

Comment: Good answer. It adds value without dealing with the OP's unresolved data structures.

Comment: Cool! Actually, the two for loop and the part that drops the picked element and making a new list are where I don't satisfy at most.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but in this way you have two element of this type: defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': ['apple'], 'r': ['rank'], 'e': ['elephant'], 't': ['tower']}) one with the starting letters and one with the ending one..... you didn't concatenate anything here :S

Comment: @Adam Smith You might want to make the adjacency list. It's almost there, but that's what OP asked for. graph = {word : startswith[word[-1]] for word in wordlist} ?

Comment: @KennyOstrom there's about a bajillion ways to do that, and it is a well-documented problem. "How to [build a graph] in an ***efficient*** way" (emphasis mine) was my take on the question. This is how to do that.

Comment: @Carlo1585 courtesy ping for the comment above

Comment: Fair enough. It's not at all clear how OP is going to represent the graph.

Comment: @KennyOstrom yes this is why I tried to avoid that question altogether.

Answer (score 1):

funny!
I hope I understand what you're talking about.

```
def transform(lst):
    graph = []
    for picked in lst:
        if len(graph)==0:
            graph.append(picked)
        else:
            ch=graph[len(graph)-1][len(graph[len(graph)-1])-1]
            world_ch=[i for i in lst if ((i not in graph)and(i[0]==ch)) ]
            if len(world_ch)==0: break
            else: graph.append(world_ch[0])
    return(graph)

lista=['apple','carloh','horse','apple','elephant','tower','rank']

print(str(transform(lista)))
```

> > ['apple', 'elephant', 'tower', 'rank']

```
print(str([[i] for i in transform(lista)]))
```

> > [['apple'], ['elephant'], ['tower'], ['rank']]